# Getting open source project's build history via AppVeyor API

Tags: git, appveyor

I am in the process of conducting a research on open source GitHub repositories, and there is this particular piece of information I would like to get about a repository: whether it is currently using a CI-service or not.

In order to do that, I locate the `*.yml` configuration file, identify the CI-provider and query its API for latest build history. Then I can verify if the latest commits of `master` branch have an associated CI-build.

For instance, if the project's using *Travis*, then querying `https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/{owner}/{repo}/builds` gives me information on the latest 50 builds, which is right what I need.

But I have been having some issues with *AppVeyor*. According to their [documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/api/projects-builds/#get-projects), the build history can be acquired via: `https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/{accountName}/{projectSlug}/history?recordsNumber={records-per-page}`. The API service request is accordingly provided with obligatory headings (`Accept` and `Authorization`). However, when I try to fetch build history for a project (e.g. `Octokit/Octokit.net`), I always receive `"Project not found or access denied."`.

Hence, am I correct in the assumption that *AppVeyor* restricts access to build information to registered project collaborators only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify that the latest commits of `master` branch have an associated CI builds you don't even need to call CI API - the required information is on GitHub already! All that you need is to check commit statuses with [Statuses API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/). Every CI system has its own unique status `context` value. For example, AppVeyor context starts from `continuous-integration/appveyor`.

Comment: Also `*.yml` configuration file is not very deterministic. For AppVeyor customer can have configuration in UI, in `appveyor.yml`, `.appveyor.yml` or any custom name. Also it can be on remote HTTP location. More info https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#configuring-build.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I guess, I've been digging in the wrong direction! The Status API does exactly what I need. Although I hoped to minimize the number of GitHub API requests due the the limits. But anyways, this is just one more request, which does not make that much of a differenece.